# Checking Connection Compression Usage

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Is there a way to **query of all the current connections** and to see if they are using [compression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/compression.html)?

I know you can query your current connection using:

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Compression";
```

This will return a table with the value column saying `ON` or `OFF`.

However, this is not what I want.  I would rather have something like `SHOW PROCESSLIST` that has a column indicating whether or not someone's connection has compression enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since compression is strictly in the scope of a session, it is currently impossible to query data from another session in MySQL directly.

---

## Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65147/27603

> Is there a way to see the SESSION variables of other active, connected users, from a superuser connection ?

No, there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in MySQL with performance schema:

```
sql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.status_by_thread WHERE VARIABLE_NAME 
LIKE 'Compression%';
+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+
| THREAD_ID | VARIABLE_NAME         | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+
|        55 | Compression           | ON             |
|        55 | Compression_algorithm | zstd           |
|        55 | Compression_level     | 3              |
|        56 | Compression           | OFF            |
|        56 | Compression_algorithm |                |
|        56 | Compression_level     | 0              |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.0012 sec)

sql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.33    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.0006 sec)
```

The original question was about MySQL 5.6, which probably didn't support this yet.